# How to fix 'bash: ask: command not found' error after installing the ASK-CLI?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I'm a beginner in Alexa skill development. I had installed `ASK-CLI` and was working properly until today and now I'm getting this error `:'bash: ask: command not found'`
I have node and git installed and working properly.

I have installed and uninstalled ASK multiple times, still not working.

Answer (score 1):

what is you OS and also what command did you use to install the cli?